# How to prove the following asymptotic behavior?

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, estimation

How to prove that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\delta r^2} \frac{\pi}{2 \cosh^2(\pi r)} \, dr = 1 + O(\delta),$$ as $\delta \to 0$?

Answer (score 0):

Almost trivial, with a CAS.  Taylor expand the exponential and use
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dr}{\cosh^2{(\pi\,r)}}=\frac{2}{\pi} \, \text{   and  } 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{r^2\,dr}{\cosh^2{(\pi\,r)}}=\frac{1}{6\pi}.$$